# Desserializar string json em obejto no android

Tags: android, json, desserialização

Gostaria de  transforma essa string em um objeto,  alias, colocar os dados da string jsom em um objeto. Não estou conseguindo, já recebi o código 200 de sucesso e também vejo que recebo os valores conforme a string abaixo, ms não consigo montar em um objeto

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://was-p.bcnet.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata$metadata#_CotacaoDolarDia",
"value": [
    {
        "cotacaoCompra": 3.9572,
        "cotacaoVenda": 3.9578,
        "dataHoraCotacao": "2019-05-10 13:08:45.718"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você recebe o *JSON* como `string` e quer mandar para um objeto?
 você pode fazer assim:

```
 try{

    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject( result.toString() );
    JSONArray Jarray = jsonResult.getJSONArray( "data" );

    if ( Jarray.length() != 0 ) 
    {
        Objeto objeto = new Objeto();
        for ( int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++ ) 
        {
            JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject( i );
            objeto.setaCampo( Jasonobject.getString( "campo" ) );
            ObjetoController.setObjeto( objeto );
        }
    }

} 
catch ( Exception e )
{
    Log.e( "error", e.getMessage() );
}
```

Mas pode ser uma lista também:

```
List<Object[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

A ideia é a mesma, mas no loop `for` colocaria algo do tipo:

```
Object[] ob = new Object[ 1 ];
ob[ 0 ] = Jasonobject.getString( "campo" );
lista.add( 0, ob );
```